# Selenium WebDriver driver.getWindowHandles() in FireFox

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver

Selenium WebDriver 2.53.1 using FireFox 47.0.1 with Java:

No matter what `driver1.getWindowHandles()` returns only one handle. In Chrome, the code below works fine and returns the correct number of handles.

Is there anyway to return multiple window handles this way using firefox?

```
    driver1 = new FirefoxDriver();

    // LOOP TO OPEN AS MANY TABS AS YOU WISH
    for(int i = 0; i < TAB_NUMBER; i++) {
       driver1.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t");
       // SLEEP FOR SPLIT SECOND TO ALLOW DRIVER TIME TO OPEN TAB
       Thread.sleep(100);
     }
    // STORE TAB HANDLES IN ARRAY LIST FOR EASY ACCESS
    ArrayList tabs1 = new ArrayList<String> (driver1.getWindowHandles());

    System.out.println(tabs1);
```

Comment: There's no guarantee whatsoever this would work in the first place, but I don't understand what the use case for manually opening a second tab. Lots of people seem to want to open a new tab using `Control+T` or similar, but no one can seem to articulate a compelling use case for it.

Comment: I used it for accessing particular urls that needed login verification.  Once I had selenium go through the login process, I was able to open new tabs and go directly to the page that I needed to access.  Then using threads to execute logic within each tab in parallel.

Comment: I see. And using separate instances while supplying the access cookie which contains the login token wouldn't work?

Comment: The website I was using would have the broswer randomly connect to one of four servers.  I needed to get one browser per server and multiple tabs sending messages to that server.  There was no guarantee that the new browser instance would be on a particular server.  It was random.  Plus for me I found it a lot easier to manipulate 10 tabs on four different browser instances than I did opening 40 different browser instances.  I am a big time novice with selenium though so any advice is welcomed.